# The form text starts with padding spaces

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have such a bootstrap form,
The text form area starts with padding:

I have to manually remove the spaces:

[image]

the codes:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/article/create/{{ b.id }}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Title</label>
        <div class="col-sm-11">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="
                Write Title Later" >
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="content" class="col-sm-1 control-label" >Content</label>
        <div class="col-sm-11">
          <textarea class="form-control" id="content" rows="10" value="
                Write Content Firstly">
                </textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Publish</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

What's the problem with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove all space between 'textarea' and '/textarea'. Here is the updated code ^^

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="/article/create/{{ b.id }}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Title</label>
        <div class="col-sm-11">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Write Title Later" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="content" class="col-sm-1 control-label" >Content</label>
        <div class="col-sm-11">
          <textarea class="form-control" id="content" rows="10" value="
                Write Content Firstly"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Publish</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```